# Upload videos with objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am to build a really complicated (at least to me) app now. The basic app is as follows:

A tab bar app with two tabs, one for local videos and the other for streaming videos.

It is simple at this stage but now i have to upload videos (either taken from iphone gallery or shoot by users) to the server.

Don't really have any idea how to do it. Please help me.

Comment: nothing about the upload part. the app as of now has one video in the resource folder that is played as the local video. and one url for a video kept statically in the code which is streamed and played when asked for.

Comment: Do you need the code for uploading videos on server.

Comment: @Gypsa: yes...that would be great if you can share the code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
    {
    NSURL *urlvideo = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];


    urlvideo contains the URL of that video file that has to be uploaded. Then convert the url into NSString type because setFile method requires NSString as a parameter

    NSString *urlString=[urlvideo path];

    NSLog(@"urlString=%@",urlString);
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"path of server"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setFile:urlString forKey:@"key foruploadingFile"];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startSynchronous];
    NSLog(@"responseStatusCode %i",[request responseStatusCode]);
    NSLog(@"responseStatusCode %@",[request responseString]);
    }
```

Hope this code will save your couple of hours.

Answer (score 0):

Using AFNetworking:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api-base-url.com"];
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar.jpg"], 0.5);
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/upload" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"avatar" fileName:@"avatar.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
}];
```