# How upload a video file to a web server iphone sdk

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to upload video to web server using `UIImagePickerController`. Please suggest me how to do or provide a sample for this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178542/upload-videos-with-objective-c

Answer (score 0):

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info

```
{

NSURL *urlvideo = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];


//urlvideo contains the URL of that video file that has to be uploaded. Then convert the url into NSString type because setFile method requires NSString as a parameter

NSString *urlString=[urlvideo path];

NSLog(@"urlString=%@",urlString);
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"path of server"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setFile:urlString forKey:@"key foruploadingFile"];

[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];

[request setDelegate:self];

[request startSynchronous];

NSLog(@"responseStatusCode %i",[request responseStatusCode]);

NSLog(@"responseStatusCode %@",[request responseString]);

}
```