# Uploading video with AFNetworking from iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, http, file-upload, afnetworking

I am posting a video file to server from my iPhone app. Currently I am using HTTP POST method.
I would like to learn about upload using AFNetworking.
Hope someone will help me.

Here is the sample HTTP posting now I am using :

```
NSString *urlString =@"http://example.com/demo/upload_video";

NSMutableURLRequest *request= [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

//userid 
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user_id\"\r\n\r\n%@", appDelegate.userid] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
if (conn) {
    webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
}
```

Comment: MKNetworkKit is also good alternative to post video on server.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178542/upload-videos-with-objective-c) may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you adding this `[httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];` at the end of your code?

Use the following code as example :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api-base-url.com"];
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar.jpg"], 0.5);
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/upload" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"avatar" fileName:@"avatar.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
}];
```

//If you want Progress Report as well, use the below code :

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
    NSLog(@"Sent %lld of %lld bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
}];
[httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
```

Comment: No
...You could have asked this in comments

Comment: @SplatterStrikes see the above example